# Revision info in timeline showing "ffffffffff gggg" instead of the real revision summary

Tags: bug, status-completed, edit-summary, timeline

Just noticed that the timeline shows `ffffffffff gggg` instead of the real revision summary:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/83329/timeline

> [image]

Same in other timelines that I checked: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21134802/timeline or https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21119035/timeline.

Comment: The developers must be testing who is actually still using the timeline view...

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think the timeline was ever officially supported. The whole layout of it is rather confusing and I have only found some limited use for it. But maybe SE will implement a less confusing version of it based on the mod-only timeline, which is much easier to understand (but doesn't show votes and full post text)

Comment: @MadScientist: I find the timeline to be quite informative; I know it isn't officially supported anymore (IIRC it was once linked to from questions but the link was removed). But I can see some room for improvement, yes.

Comment: By the way you missed the `hhh` (it was much harder to find). Also, no revision summary was removed as part of this "experiment".

Comment: @MartijnPieters nope, it was never linked. Started as experiment by Jeff and never advanced to the next level.

Comment: @Sklivvz you just lost your diamond... let me take a picture... ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So you found out my evil scheme of testing who uses that timeline uh?

*You foiled my plan once again Batman, but the next time it won't be so simple!*

---

Fix going out now. `rev 2014.1.15.1851` on meta and `rev 2014.1.15.1301` elsewhere

Comment: Before accepting the answer I want statistics of how many people uses the timeline! :P

Comment: Exactly four! :-)